# Verify multiple conditions with contains(where:)

Tags: swift, where-clause

With this code I enable a button if any form value is not `nil`:

```
myButton.isEnabled = !myForm.values.contains(where: { $0 == nil })
```

Is there any way to add multiple checks? I want to enable my button:

- if the value of any field is nil (done, as you can see above);
- if the value of any field is > 0;
- if the value of any field is < 2;

(that is, the value should NOT be nil and should NOT be outside the range 0.0 - 2.0)

Can I still use [contains(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains) to do it?

MyForm is a dictionary like this one:

```
 ["oct": nil, 
     "jan": Optional(3666.0), 
     "nov": nil, 
     "apr": nil, 
     "sep": nil, 
     "feb": nil, 
     "jul": nil, 
     "mar": nil, 
     "dec": nil, 
     "may": nil, 
     "jun": nil, 
     "aug": nil]
```

(strange enough, due to the behavior of a 3rd party library, it accepts `nil` values)

Comment: Please tell us what the type of `myForm.values` is.

Comment: It is a dictionary

Comment: Please read this and edit your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JeremyP, if you don't want to answer, none is forcing you to do it! There's nothing wrong in my question! I simply said THAT code works with one condition, you haven't to know much else! I asked if that code can be reused with where when you add conditions! And anybody here is not even reading the question (is it possible to use "where"? Yes/No)

Comment: Yes, it is possible, the closure can contain any – but not too complex – expression which returns a boolean value.

Comment: You had three answers (two now deleted) none of which do what you want. This is because your question is incomplete. Read the link I posted in my previous comment and then ask yourself if the code in your question meets the criteria.

Comment: @JeremyP: please, don't tell me your problem is I didn't mention values was a dictionary! Questions where deleted because anyone is simply reading what he wants to read! I don't need an how-to, I want to know if WHERE is more "powerful" than it seems!

Comment: @3000 No my problem is that your question is not good enough to give you the answer you wanted. If you just wanted to know "can I use more complex boolean conditions in a `contains(where:)`" my answer and th4kman's answer were sufficient (also vadian's comment above). However, your comments to both suggest you do not want the answer to the general question, you want an answer that works for you in this specific case. There's nothing wrong with that, just give enough information to answer to your satisfaction.

Comment: @JeremyP: I edited my question, I hope you like it this way, ok?  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you want to enable the button if there is at least one `Double` value in range `0.0..<2.0` you don't need to call `values`. You can call `contains` on the dictionary directly. The `where` keyword is syntactic sugar and can be omitted when using trailing closure syntax.

The code uses the pattern matching operator to check the range.

```
myButton.isEnabled = myForm.contains { (_, value) in
    guard let value = value as? Double else { return false }
    return 0.0..<2.0 ~= value
}
```

If you want to enable the button if **all** values are `Double` in the given range you have to check inverted

```
myButton.isEnabled = !myForm.contains { (_, value) in
    guard let value = value as? Double else { return true }
    return !(0.0..<2.0 ~= value)
}
```

Comment: Any value in the dictionary must be not nil and in the range 0.0-2.0, so not "at least one Double" but any Double value in the dictionary must be in that range

Comment: Perfect, thanks (and sorry for not giving enough information)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just by filtering all values like this:

```
myButton.isEnabled = !myForm.values.filter { 
    if let value = $0 { return value.field > 0.0 && value.field < 2.0 }
    return false 
}.count > 0
```

`contains` function is not appropriate solution in your case, because it should be used when you need to check if array contain some specific element. But in your case you need to check if values is in specific range.
It is possible to use `contains` function but it is not correct way

Comment: Ok, ok, but the question was: is it possible with 'where'?  :-)

Comment: If I run your code I get: "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Bool'"

Comment: (the error is with the final count. If I remove it, I get another error: Cannot convert value of type '[Any?]' to expected argument type 'Bool')

Comment: How it is possible if I'm using some `field` property, which probably is not exist in your code

Comment: I think you missed this part `.count > 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165399/discussion-between-taras-chernyshenko-and-3000).

Comment: There's no field property at all: if you declare v = $0 you can use it inside the following block: !myForm.values.filter{ if let v = $0 { return v > 0.0 && v < 2.0 }; return false }.count>0